# C++ cast struct dynamically based on subtype

Tags: c++, struct, casting

So I am currently attempting to create my own enitity component architecture and I am having some issues.

I am storing my components as a struct, eg

```
struct BaseComponent
{
  bool isValid;
}

struct ComponentA : BaseComponent
{
  int someValForA;
}

struct ComponentB : BaseComponent
{
  int someValForB
}

ComponentB* compB = new ComponentB()
compB->someValForB = 10;
BaseComponent* baseComp = compB

ComponentB* comp = (ComponentB*) baseComp
```

I would like my system to be able to store the structs of varing inheritance. so I would need to use a vector of pointers. The problem is, how do I cast them back to their origional derived struct dynamically without knowing their origional subtype? Can I determine their derived type through code without an enum since I want to implement this in a library.

I will also take answer that also give alternate approaches to implementing this system, keeping in mind that I want to develop it. Please be specfic and give a code example if possible to help.

Thank-you for reading :)

PS. This is a repost of another question I uploaded today. It was closed as a duplicate question, yet the duplicate didn't even come close to answering my question. I request that you understand the exactness of my question by talking to me through comments instead of preventing anyone else from helping. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I had few time the same problem. But as you said I always ended up adding and enum "type" in the BaseComponent and initializing it to its specific type while constructing the subClass (or subStruct)... dynamically getting the type is not possible

Comment: Yeah, that is my backup plan but if there is another way, then id like to know but thanks alot for your comment anyways :)

Comment: See in java I could check if the parent class was an instance of a derived class.

Comment: If your base class is polymorphic, you can use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

Comment: @Holt how would I do that??? Could you please give an example

Comment: Why you do it like this? Why don't you make `virtual methods` in the base class and work only with the `BaseComponent`? I can post an example, but it will not answer your question.

Comment: @Nick yes please do... I am trying to create an entity based component architecture and as many different approaches would help, even if it just broadens my tool set. The reason I didn't use methods is because each struct is intended to be used as data storage for each entity, but still please add it as an answer I would love that :) thank you

Comment: Why do you store these objects all together, if you need to treat them differently ?

Comment: @Quentin Because an entity is created by adding components, and then systems will see if an entity has the required components and perform the logic, like a lock and key. So things need to be setup so they can be looped over so small entities and large ones can be processed in the same way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than throwing out type information, then checking whether every component is the one you're looking after, I suggest you use a container that maps a type to its component (or tells you it doesn't have it).

```
using TypeId = unsigned int;

namespace detail_typeId {
    TypeId idCounter = 0u;
}

template <class T>
TypeId const idFor = detail_typeId::idCounter++;
```

This trick uses the side-effect in the initialization of the specializations of `idFor<T>` to provide a unique identifier value for each type, that can be used as a key. You could also use [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index), but that forces you to have polymorphic classes as components. This approach also has the advantage of producing contiguous integer identifiers, which span the range `[0, idCounter - 1]`.

```
struct Component {};
```

A base class for your components.

```
struct Entity {

    template <class T, class... Args>
    void addComponent(Args &&... args) {
        if(!comps.emplace(
            idFor<T>, std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        ).second)
            throw std::runtime_error("Component already present.");
    }

    template <class T>
    T *getComponent() {
        auto found = comps.find(idFor<T>);
        return found == end(comps)
            ? nullptr
            : static_cast<T*>(found->second.get());
    }

    std::map<TypeId, std::unique_ptr<Component>> comps;
};
```

Here we see the actual storage of the components, as well as two convenience functions to access them. The map allows us to retrieve any component based on its type.

Example usage with three user-defined components :

```
struct CompA : Component { int attribA; };
struct CompB : Component { int attribB; };
struct CompC : Component { int attribC; };

int main() {
    Entity e;
    e.addComponent<CompA>();
    e.addComponent<CompB>();

    if(CompA *c = e.getComponent<CompA>()) {
        std::cout << "Retrieved component A\n";
        c->attribA = 42;
    }

    if(CompB *c = e.getComponent<CompB>()) {
        std::cout << "Retrieved component B\n";
        c->attribB = 42;
    }

    if(CompC *c = e.getComponent<CompC>()) {
        std::cout << "Retrieved component C\n";
        c->attribC = 42;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Didn't retrieve component C\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Retrieved component A
Retrieved component B
Didn't retrieve component C
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a87ff17230391d7c)

Comment: Omg that covers so much and helps me in every way!!! Thank you so much!!! I hope others wanting to learn entity based components find this because this is what I wanted and I couldn't find it. Brilliant description. Thankyou

Comment: You have answered my question, but as another quick one, you use "template <class T, class... Args> void addComponent(Args &&... args) {" I am not too familar with template but I have a rydimentary understanding and plan on doing research on it, but what does the "Class... Args" do?

Comment: @ZacShepherd `class... Args` is a *variadic template parameter pack*. The combination of `Args &&...` and `std::forward` is known as *perfect forwarding*, and makes the `addComponent` function able to take any number of parameters, and transmit them as-is to `std::make_unique`. They are the parameters for `CompX`'s constructor, if you're not familiar with `std::make_unique`. The whole thing is an extra, though : `getComponent` could very well just take in a `std::unique_ptr<T>` and let the caller do the construction himself.

Answer (score 5):

If your base class is polymorphic, you can use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to convert back to the original (a bit like `instanceof` in Java):

Let's say you have the following classes:

```
struct Base {
    // We need this or any other virtual member to make Base polymorphic
    virtual ~Base () { }
};

struct Derived1: public Base {
    void foo () {
        std::cout << "foo\n";
    }
};

struct Derived2: public Base {
    void bar () {
        std::cout << "bar\n";
    }
};
```

Then you can store these values in a `vector` of `Base*`<sup>1</sup> (the destructor of `Base` should be `virtual` in order for this to work properly):

```
std::vector<Base*> bases;
bases.push_back(new Derived1());
bases.push_back(new Derived2());
bases.push_back(new Derived2());
bases.push_back(new Derived1());
```

Then you can get back to the derived class using [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

```
for (auto *pbase: bases) {
    if (auto *d = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(pbase)) {
        d->foo();
    }
    if (auto *d = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(pbase)) {
        d->bar();
    }
}
```

[`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) will returns a null pointer if the cast fails, so you will never call `d->foo()` if `pbase` was originally `Derived2*` so it is safe.

Note that if `Base` is not polymorphic (try removing the `virtual`), you cannot use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) (compiler error).

<sub><sup>1</sup> Note that instead of using a raw pointer `Base*`, you could (should) use a smart pointer to avoid having to free the memory manually (e.g. [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)). If you do this, you will have to use [`dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) instead of `dynamic_cast`.</sub>

Comment: Thank you that helps alot, I will accept this as an answer after more people have posted. Also, I have heard that dynamic_cast and I assume dynamic_pointer_cast have a heavier drawn than static_cast. I am not familiar with the extent of this and should I be taking it into consideration for my algorithm?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` will check if the cast is valid, while `static_cast` does not, so it is slower but it is the only way (as far as I know) to do what you want (with static_cast you would get a bad pointer).

Comment: Ok, so the extra weight on the method is just because it is safe... This seems like something that I could accept as a draw back for safe secure code... Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 2):

You can get information about the type of a variable with RTTI like:

```
 (typeid(*baseComp) == typeid(ComponentB))
```

which is true in the case of your example.

Comment: And is this faster or more recommended then using dynamic_cast? Also looks awesome, same with every answer, I'm going to accept them tomorrow morning for me (its late at night now) to give some more people a chance to post, and then I will accept ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do something like this. It is not as professional as Holt's answer, but it share same disadvantages. More about them later.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base {
       virtual int what() const = 0;
       virtual ~Base(){}
};

struct Derived1 : Base {
       static constexpr int ME = 1;

       int what() const{
              return ME;
       }
};

struct Derived2 : Base {
       static constexpr int ME = 2;

       int what() const{
              return ME;
       }
};

using pBase = std::unique_ptr<Base>;

void doSomething(pBase &base){
       switch(base->what()){
       case Derived1::ME :
              std::cout << "Derived1" << std::endl;
              break;

       case Derived2::ME :
              std::cout << "Derived2" << std::endl;
              break;

       default:
              std::cout << "huh?" << std::endl;

       }
}

int main(){
       pBase base1{ new Derived1() };
       pBase base2{ new Derived2() };

       doSomething(base1);
       doSomething(base2);

       //no need to call delete
}
```

I did the code using `C++11` with `smart pointer`. If you did not worked with `C++11` - check it, you'll love it.

## Why this code is less professional than Holt's code?

Because instead of types and casts, it rely on simple `int` values, that are made specifically for identify the type.

However in my opinion, main question is quite different:

## What is the disadvantage of both codes?

In both codes, the client must know all derived classes. In Holt's answer this is the part with `if statements`. In my answer this is the `switch statement`.

What will happen if there is new derived class Derived3 ? You need to change the client code.

I believe you can do this with polymorphism and work only with `Base` class, without any casts.

## Example

there are lots of examples like this - figures, people (students, professors), cars (sport, pickups, suv's, trucks). This happens to be my favorite:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Shape {
       virtual float area() const = 0;

       virtual const char *name() const = 0;

       virtual ~Shape(){}
};

struct Square : Shape {
       Square(float a) : a(a){

       }

       const char *name() const override{
              return "Quadrat"; // this has nothing to do with class name
       }

       float area() const override{
              return a * a;
       }

private:
       float a;
};

struct Circle : Shape {
       Circle(float r) : r(r){

       }

       const char *name() const override{
              return "Circle";
       }

       float area() const override{
              return PI * r * r;
       }

private:
       constexpr static float PI = 3.14159;

       float r;
};

using pShape = std::unique_ptr<Shape>;

void doSomething(pShape &base){
       std::cout     << base->name()
                     << " has area of "
                     << base->area()
                     << "m2"
                     << std::endl;
}

int main(){
       pShape base1{ new Square(5) };
       pShape base2{ new Circle(5) };

       doSomething(base1);
       doSomething(base2);

       //no need to call delete
}
```

In many OOP languages such `Java`, `C#` or `PHP`, the base `Shape` class is called `interface`. Notice how it define methods, but does not include any implementation details.

This allows derived classes to be implemented in different compile units and client code has no idea what class it works with.